# How can I set up a mediation analysis for a logistic regression in R? (Explaining further utilization of mediation package in R)

Tags: regression, logistic-regression

I'm working on seeing whether I can predict substance use diagnosis (dichotomous, 0 = none, 1 = a diagnosis) from sexual orientation (dummy coded; 0 = straight/heterosexual, 1 = LGB). I'm also interested in whether stress score can predict diagnosis. I want to do a **mediation** analysis but for the life of me, I cannot seem to grasp how to do this in R.

I have dummy coded the LGB variable to run a basic logistic regression but I'm at a loss when it's coming to how to appropriately set up the mediation analysis where I'm testing whether stress can be explaining the LGB --> Substance use diagnosis relationship.

I have utilized chatGPT and it has given me the following advice:

logit_model <- glm(substance_use ~ sexual_minority_status, data = your_data, family = "binomial")
summary(logit_model)

mediator_model <- lm(stress ~ sexual_minority_status, data = your_data)
summary(mediator_model)

outcome_model <- lm(substance_use ~ stress + sexual_minority_status, data = your_data)
summary(outcome_model)

**This code is where I am having the most trouble**
mediation_model <- mediate(mediator_model, outcome_model, treat = "sexual_minority_status", mediator = "stress")
summary(mediation_model)
I reference "stress" as mydataframe$sum and have sexual minority status dummy coded as "dummy.lgb".